# How to wrap C file with extern variables with Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I want to wrap a quite long C function published by a scientist with Cython. I am following

http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html#interfacing-with-c

and I am able to replicate the examples with numpy support.

I am confused about what to do (or to do anything at all) about variables declared as extern in the library.cpp. Obviously, I will have a main.py that will call this function, not a main.cpp. How should I declare `ini_flag` and `A` and pass to `func`? Is there any other way than making them arguments to the function? If possible I would prefer not to edit original library.cpp file.

```
// main.cpp:
int ini_flag=0, *A;
void main(){
    func(...)
    ...
}

// library.cpp:
extern int ini_flag, *A;
void func(...){
    if (ini_flag==0){
         // malloc and initialize A
         ini_flag=1;
    }

    // use A and do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a corresponding `library.hpp` file:

```
int ini_flag, *A;
void func(...)
```

And then in Cython:

```
cdef extern from "library.hpp":
    int ini_flag, *A
    void func(...)
```

Then you can then use them normally in Cython.